# Android MultiSelectListPreference with "Select All" checkbox in the title

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences, selectall, android-multiselectlistpreference

I am new to Android. I have a MultiSelectListPreference and I would be able to check/uncheck all the boxes, possibly through a "Select All" checkbox next to the category title, in short something like this:

[image]

This is my MultiSelectListPreference from my preference xml file:

```
<MultiSelectListPreference
    android:title="Items list"
    android:key="itemsList"
    android:entries="@array/list"
    android:entryValues="@array/listValues"
    android:defaultValue="@array/listValues">
</MultiSelectListPreference>
```

Here the arrays:

```
<string-array name = "list">
     <item>Item 1</item>
     <item>Item 2</item>
     <item>Item 3</item>
     <item>Item 4</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name = "listValues">
     <item>1</item>
     <item>2</item>
     <item>3</item>
     <item>4</item>
</string-array>
```

Is there any way to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

add [setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)) to checkbox in title. 
In onCheckedChanged callback go over all items in listadapter and mark that checked

and check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274340/how-can-i-implement-a-select-all-option-for-multi-select-list-preference)

Comment: Hi ant, thanks for the answer. Since I'm a noob, first of all I don't know how to put the checkbox next to the title in the multi list select preference. Moreover, I already checked the answer that you've linked but it didn't seem appropriate for me or, most likely, I didn't understand how to adapt it to my case.